# Assigning labels to train data in CNN

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I'm new to kaggle, and and I'm wondering how to assign labels to my test data.

Both my train and test folder have the format

```
1
2
3
etc...
```

[image: This is my input folder. These are in a zipped folder]

train.txt contains labels like so:

```
train/0.jpg 5
train/1.jpg 1
train/2.jpg 10
train/3.jpg 2
train/4.jpg 22
train/5.jpg 3
etc...
```

I understand I need to loop though and assign the class number to each of the training images. But not sure how, I've looked online but the data is in different formats.

Comment: If you define your exact problem would bet better

Answer (score 1):

Firstly read the .txt file and make path list and labels:

```
with open('train.txt', 'r') as f:
     path_label = f.readlines() # returns a list

# seperate paths and labels
paths = [i.strip().split()[0] for i in path_label] 
labels = [i.strip().split()[1] for i in path_label]
```

Then you can read and fed the data to your model.

Comment: I've now looped through each line, seperated out the path and label from each line, and should be able to assign the label to each class name now. Thanks for your help